# How to setup nginx and a subdomain

Tags: git, apache, nginx

i have gitlab installed on my server and it works on all domains eg: git.lars-dev.de, lars-dev.de and *.lars-dev.de how I can run gitlab only on git.lars-dev.de and another subdomain on files.lars-dev.de?

my lars-dev conf:

```
server {
    listen   *:80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/webdata/lars-dev.de/htdocs;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name lars-dev.de;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

and the gitlab configuration:

```
upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen *:80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name git.lars-dev.de;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

Comment: you want gitlab to run on 2 urls? git and files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this line of code: `listen *:80;`

to solve the problem I must use this: `listen 80;`